# Just can't figure it out: Unexpectedly found nil error

Tags: xcode, swift

```
cell.clubCommentText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as? String
```

Getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like the value for key "text" either does not exist or is not convertible to a string. Try taking out `as? String` and see if that works and also make sure that value is being created.

Comment: `cell.clubCommentText.text = object.stringForKey("text") ?? "defaultString"`

Comment: Where is the `object` created`

Comment: Either `cell` or  `clubCommentText` or `object` is `nil`. Check that.. And stop using `valueForKey` unless `object` is an `NSManagedObject` instance or you really need KVC.  @LeoDabus the optional down casting does certainly not cause the crash

Comment: @vadian he is probably trying to access a value that has never being saved. I thing the problem is the lack of the `??` nil coalescing operator

Comment: @LeoDabus The property `text` of `UILabel` is optional so assigning `nil` won't cause a crash.

Comment: Not optional? it is implicitly unwrapped optional!

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.clubCommentText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as? String                       This is where the object is being created. @vadian what should I use instead? Im actually new to swift.

Answer (score 0):

Object for key may return nil if not set because it doesn't know what type it is yet. So you should use the nil coalescing operator to avoid this.

```
 cell.clubCommentText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as? String ?? "DefaultText"
```

You check if the object exits as a string (as? String) and if it doesn't you create a new one (??...)

Answer (score 0):

check whether the textfield inside the cell was loaded correctly